# How can CGPoints be vectors?

Tags: objective-c, math, vector, cgpoint

Lets say you have the following method:

```
CGPoint vectorSubtraction(CGPoint a, CGPoint b) {
    return CGPointMake(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
}
```

And you use the following points:

```
Point A: (1,4)
Point B: (10,3)
```

If you use the `vectorSubtraction` method, you get:

A POINT at `(9,-1)`.

Now, I would understand if `(9,-1)` was the *vector* from the first to the second point (and it is), but I don't understand why the vector itself is a POINT. Vectors by definition have a direction and magnitude. How can a point have direction and magnitude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested in the background of this question, it's almost certainly form [Ray Wenderlich's Sprite Kit Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners). Search that link for the heading `"Shooting Projectiles"`.

In terms of the situations where a point can be considered a vector, it can if the other end of the vector is *implicit* rather than explicit.

In this particular case, the point is being treated as a vector from the origin `(0,0)` to the point given.

So the actual vector calculation is (you appear to have the points reversed by the way):

```
(0,0)->(10,3) - (0,0)->(1,4) = (0,0)->(9,-1)
```

Comment: I am still kind of confused...By origin do you mean the screen's frame's origin?

Comment: @EvilAegis, the origin in a 2D Euclidean geometric setting is the point at `(0,0)`. Whether that's your screen frames origin depends entirely on the mapping of your screen frame, something I'm not au fait with. I'm talking more from a purely mathematical viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Approaching the problem from a (not actually) different direction:

> How can a point have direction and magnitude?

So like this:

```
double direction = atan2(point.y, point.x);
double magnitude = hypot(point.x, point.y);
```

Good old Descartes coordinate system.

Comment: I meant how a point can intrinsically have a direction and magnitude. Not quite how to make a direction and magnitude based on a point

Comment: @EvilAegis But that's how it's defined. This is not just my random arbitrary idea. As you have already got to know, the point is just one end of a vector of which the other end is the origin. Look up what these functions do, work it out on paper and you'll see I'm right.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought a CGPoint was defined as a struct with just a x & y. I didn't think the compiler made vectors based on the origin

Comment: @EvilAegis A `CGPoint` is just a struct with an x and y member. The compiler doesn't define anything. Programmers use logic and maths to define vectors based on points. This has nothing to do with the compiler whatsoever, it is a widely-accepted mathematical concept, let's say an *assumption.*

Comment: One question, by the (0,0) origin, do you mean the screen's frame's origin?

Comment: @EvilAegis No. Again, this has absolutely nothing to do with iOS, Objective-C, the compiler or anything else. It's just maths. It's the point `(0, 0)` in *an arbitrary* coordinate system. Try to abstrahate.

Comment: OH I see! So even though it is a point, I should think of it as a vector from an imaginary origin? I think I get it now!

Comment: @EvilAegis You don't have to, but you can. In this case, it is used as a vector. In other cases, it may not be used as one.